# appcfg.py returns unauthorized client when update with --oauth_refresh_token

Tags: python, google-app-engine, travis-ci

As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2) to use passwordless authentication I have to provide --oauth_refresh_token. To obtain token I have to look in .appcfg_oauth_tokens, but since I use gcloud command line tool credentials are now stored in $GCLOUD_SDK_CONF/credentials. If I get refresh token from there and run appcfg.py upload --oauth_refresh-token= app/ my app can be succesfully uploaded, when I provide this refresh token to Travis configuration I got unauthorized client

ERROR client.py:440 Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}

Is there any way to get refresh token for Travis (I also tried drone.io with native support GAE deploy, but the same thin happend).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused with appcfg.py from gcloud tools and google app engine itself. Switching back to GAE appcfg.py resolved the issue (i.e. /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py --oauth2 --noauth_local_webserver update .) And now I have as stated .appcfg_oauth2_tokens where refresh_token is saved. I can use this token to auto deploy app when build is successful.